# How can I render other controller(server) file in express?

Tags: express, router

I am making simple `Todo list` web application with express. Starting with `experss generator`.

I have `app.js` file and my lecture describes put all codes in `app.js` file, but I want to keep them separately.

So I generate `todos.js` in `routes` folder. This is my simple structure

```
project
  |-app.js
  |
  |-routes
      |-index.js
      |-todos.js
```

I want to add get, post, put, and delete;CRUD function on my `todos.js`
How can I do that? I checked their official menual, but didn't really understand it well (http://expressjs.com/ko/4x/api.html#router)

Can anybody help me to understand it or explain how to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this.

todos.js

```
router.get('/',function(req,res,next) {...} );
router.put('/',function(req,res,next) {...} );
router.post('/', function(req,res,next() {...});
router.delete('/', function(req,res,next() {...});

module.exports = router;
```

index.js

```
var todosAPI = require('./todos.js');

var configRoutes = function(app){
    app.use('/todos',todosAPI);
}
module.exports = configRoutes;
```

app.js

```
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes/index.js');
routes(app);
```

------------------- **Without index.js** -----------------------

todos.js

```
router.get('/',function(req,res,next) {...} );
router.put('/',function(req,res,next) {...} );
router.post('/', function(req,res,next() {...});
router.delete('/', function(req,res,next() {...});

module.exports = router;
```

app.js

```
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes/todos.js');
app.use('/todos',routes)
```

Comment: Do I need index.js??

Comment: In this case, no. But if you had multiple 'API's it would be useful.

Comment: It does not work on mine. I think I need to create new files and folders to try.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to try it soon